# How to add a second condition to strategy.entry()?

Tags: pine-script

How do i add a condition of "strategy entry" where i only want signals below the 200EMA to be taken into consideration

```
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, 100.0, when = buySignal)
```

This is the current code. How do i add the conditions to this?

Answer (score 0):

- Get the `ema` first
- Add this to your already existing condition `buySignal`

This should give you an idea:

```
ema_length = 200
ema_source = close

ema = ta.ema(ema_source, ema_length)
is_ema_good = (close < ema)

if (is_ema_good and buySignal)
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, 100.0)
```